# /media, /mnt, /run and automounting

Tags: fedora, mount, directory-structure

[As of Fedora15, a new directory under root was introduced.](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-March/150031.html) A couple of quotes:

> i.e. /var is "persistant runtime data" and /run
>     is "volatile runtime data", and /etc is "persistant system config
>     data", and so on.
>   ...
>   only early boot stuff should use /run, for now

I am running F18 with the default Gnome desktop and am very new to it. This morning I noticed that automounting defaults to /var/media. Why is that? **When are /media, /mnt and /run/mount used?**

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but you may be interested in what the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard has to say about /mount and /mnt. http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT

Comment: `/run` is a centralized place for all sorts of volatile runtime data, pulling together stuff previously scattered all over the place. `/media` is gone, `/mnt` is the traditional place for the system administrator to mount stuff temporarily (e.g. an external disk for backups).

Comment: Forgot that recently removable media are mounted under /run/media/username, so only that user has access to them.