# How to organize mount points of connecting devices?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, usb, automounting, mtp

When I am connecting my external HDD to my Ubuntu box, it mounts several partitions under

```
/media/<username>/<uuid>
```

When I am connecting my mobile phone, it mounts under

```
/var/run/user/<userid>/<unknowncode>
```

Can we have any systematic behavior here? Can we program, where to mount some specific media or devices?

Comment: It depends on which software does the automounts for you.

Comment: So, this is obviously, the question.

Comment: `/media/<username>/<uuid>` is probably handled by `udisks`, which allows non-root users to handle removable media. In GNOME desktop environment, `gnome-disks` is probably the primary configuration tool for `udisks`. If that's not enough, read `man udisks` for more pointers. On the other hand, your mobile phone connection is probably handled by MTP, which is not an actual filesystem. The problem is, there are multiple tools for handling MTP and I don't know which of them you're using. `jmtpfs`? `gvfs-mtp`? Something else?

Comment: Related - possible dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169571/what-is-the-difference-between-mounting-in-fstab-and-by-mounting-in-file-manager/169576#169576

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/media-mnt-run-and-automounting

Comment: See here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Mount_to_.2Fmedia_.28udisks2.29.